# How to handle backslash character in PowerShell -replace string operations?

Tags: powershell, replace, backslash

I am using -replace to change a path from source to destination. However I am not sure how to handle the \ character. For example:

```
$source = "\\somedir"
$dest = "\\anotherdir"

$test = "\\somedir\somefile"

$destfile = $test -replace $source, $dest
```

After this operation, $destfile is set to

```
"\\\anotherdir\somefile"
```

What is the correct way to do this to avoid the triple backslash in the result?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try the following:

```ps1
$source = "\\\\somedir"
```

You were only matching 1 backslash when replacing, which gave you the three `\\\` at the start of your path.

The backslash is a `regex` escape character so `\\` will be seen as, match only one `\` and not two `\\`. As the first backslash is the escape character and not used to match.

Another way you can handle the backslashes is to use the [`Regex.Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) function from .NET, i.e:

```ps1
$source = [regex]::escape('\\somedir')
```

Comment: `[regex]::Escape()` is the safer solution, because it will handle other special characters (like `+` or parentheses) as well.

Comment: thanks, this worked though I used the regex solution

Comment: ```[regex]::Escape()``` doesn't work as expected for paths containing '.'

Answer (score 1):

I came here after having issues with `Test-Path` and `Get-Item` not working with a UNC path with spaces. Part of the problem was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567844/get-childitem-and-non-breaking-space), and the other part was solved as follows:

```
$OrginalPath = "\\Hostname\some\path with spaces"
$LiteralPath = $OriginalPath -replace "^\\{2}", "\\?\UNC\"
```

Result:
`\\?\UNC\Hostname\some\path with spaces`

For completeness, putting this into `Test-Path` returns true (assuming that path actually exists). As [@Sage Pourpre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934946/sage-pourpre) says, one needs to use `-LiteralPath`:

`Test-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath`
or
`Get-Item -LiteralPath $LiteralPath`

The [replacement operator `-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) uses regex.

- `^` means start of string.
- `\` is the escape character, so we escape the `\` with a `\`.
- As we have two `\`'s we tell regex to look for exactly 2 occurrences of `\` using `{2}`.

Instead of using `{2}`, you can do what [@Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2215029/richard) has said and use four `\`. One escapes the other.

Give it a try [here](http://regexr.com/6f71l).