# Cannot replace a string by another string stored in variable

Tags: powershell

I typed this:

```
$folder = 'c:\test'
"c:\test" -replace $folder ""
```

but get this error:

```
At line:1 char:25
+ "c:\test" -replace $folder ""
+                         ~~
Unexpected token '""' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

This doesn't help me
[How to handle backslash character in PowerShell -replace string operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001694/how-to-handle-backslash-character-in-powershell-replace-string-operations)

Comment: You forgot `,`.

Comment: Your code isn't going to do anything once you fix it as `test` doesn't contain `c:\test`... instead try `$folder -replace 'test',''`

Comment: @PetSerAl thanks I'm used to another language for now :)

Comment: @JamesC. yes in fact it doesn't replace, should I ask another question ?

Comment: @user310291 The answer to the question you linked to already explains what else you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma and I think you have your input string and search string backwards.

```
$folder -replace "test",""
```